# Flutter: A build function returned null

Tags: flutter

I have a `StatefulWidget` for displaying page with data, and I am using `setState` for returning the page, but when I am running apps show error like this:

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1PbO.jpg "screenshot"

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:codelab_dicoding/data.dart';
import 'package:codelab_dicoding/detail.dart';

class BreakFast extends StatefulWidget{


  @override
  _BreakFastState createState() => _BreakFastState();
}

class _BreakFastState extends State<BreakFast>{
  List<Container> daftarBreakfast = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    Future <_BreakFastState>_breakfast() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < breakfast.length; i++) {
      final namaMakanan = breakfast[i];
      final String gambar = namaMakanan["gambar"];
      final String bahan = namaMakanan["bahan"];

      daftarBreakfast.add(Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Card(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                // tag: namaMakanan['nama'],
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () =>
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => Detail(
                                    nama: namaMakanan['nama'],
                                    gambar: gambar,
                                    bahan: bahan
                                  ),
                            )),
                    child: Image.network(
                      gambar,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
              Text(
                namaMakanan['nama'],
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )
            ],
          ))));
    }

  }

  setState(() {
    return BreakFast();
  });
  }

}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I just omitted some variables for simplicity.

Comment: It might be my mistake, but did I see that you put `setState` in `build`?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes you were making, like you were using `setState` inside `build()` and you also had your `_breakfast()` inside the `build()`. Check out this code, it is working.

```
class BreakFast extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BreakFastState createState() => _BreakFastState();
}

class _BreakFastState extends State<BreakFast> {
  List<Container> daftarBreakfast = List();

  // put it outside build()
  Future<_BreakFastState> _breakfast() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < breakfast.length; i++) {
      final namaMakanan = breakfast[i];
      final String gambar = namaMakanan["gambar"];
      final String bahan = namaMakanan["bahan"];

      daftarBreakfast.add(Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Card(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                // tag: namaMakanan['nama'],
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => Detail(nama: namaMakanan['nama'], gambar: gambar, bahan: bahan),
                    )),
                    child: Image.network(
                      gambar,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
              Text(
                namaMakanan['nama'],
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )
            ],
          ))));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // return BreakFast();
    return FlutterLogo(size: 400); // try this 
  }
}
```

Comment: i try code from you, but when i am running , the screen not error but, still blank

Comment: Then the problem is in your `BreakFast` widget. Check out the updated code.

Comment: you must add a return in the build function. use a futureBuilder widget to use the future returned from your func

Comment: @Salma. I am already returning a widget from build and the OP  isn't using `FutureBuilder`.